# ListView delays items before showing

Tags: android, listview

I've done the tutorial in Android Developer site.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

And I've added a ViewHolder. Still the list delays items when I scroll down. It's just around 1 or 2 seconds but it's still obvious. I managed to take this screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

I've read about LazyList and UniversalImageLodaer but the question is do they work if I get the image from res/drawable instead of url? or is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: How many images are there? LazyLoading with UIL or picasso would help

Comment: If you're still using the code from your previous questions, keep in mind that the `getIdentifier()` method is fairly slow and should be avoided in the `getView()` method of the adapter.

Comment: @Raghunandan around 10 I think. all around size of 25 KBs resized too 100 width(or)100 height using BitMap Decode.

Comment: @Luksprog  so, any other ways of getting resource id without calling that?

Comment: There is no other way, just that you shouldn't do it there. You should do it upfront(like in the adapter's constructor) for all the rows and then have those ids already available in the `getView()` method. A library as Picasso is another good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load image for listview. It can load image from resource.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
```